# Correct way to access value of an input initialized with a prop when button is clicked in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that consists of an input field and a button. When the button is clicked I want to run an update function that is also inherited from the parent controller. In the react documentation they have an onchange handler attached to this input and they get the new value of the input with the onchange event object. However in my case I get an event object describing the button, not the input field. What is the correct way to access the new input field value from handle click?

```
class QuoteButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick () {
    this.props.onQuoteUpdate(//what should go here?)
  }
  render() {
    const cost = this.props.cost;
    return (
      <div>
        <Input value={cost}/>
        <Button basic color='green' onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit Quote</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to change Input value in `QuoteButton` component?

Comment: Yes, The input value will be changed by the user of the app by editing the input field. Then the user will click the button which will use the onQuoteUpdate function provided by the parent component to update the cost property in the parent component, causing the QuoteButton Component to be rerendered with the new cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you a going to change input value in this component you need to use react states (if you don't use state management libraries such as mobx or redux). In most cases input have to be a controlled component.

After component was mounted add cost value to states. You also need appropriate handler for input.

P.S. You could use arrow functions to avoid binding handlers in constructor.

```
class QuoteButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { inputValue: '' };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({inputValue: this.props.cost});
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.onQuoteUpdate(this.state.inputValue);
    }

    handleInputChange = event => {
        this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                <Button basic color='green' onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit Quote</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Hope it helps